# IOS8 and Swift multiple views with gestures dont work

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, gestures

I'm trying to build a user interface based on generic classes which are based on the same extension of the UIViewController class. This example puts squares on the screen and the tap event would be dealt with in the parent class, but it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Main ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //FIRST SQUARE
    let widget1 = TestWidget()
    widget1.viewX = 10
    widget1.viewY = 10
    self.view.addSubview(widget1.view)
    self.addChildViewController(widget1)
    widget1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    //SECOND SQUARE
    let widget2 = TestWidget()
    widget2.viewX = 100
    widget2.viewY = 100
    self.view.addSubview(widget2.view)
    self.addChildViewController(widget2)
    widget2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  }

}
```

Here is the TestWidget class:

```
class TestWidget : UIViewController {

  var viewX : CGFloat!

  var viewY : CGFloat!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let square = UIView()
    square.frame = CGRect(x : viewX, y : viewY, width: 50, height: 50)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.view.addSubview(square)
    //GESTURE PART
    var tapForSquare = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapForSquare.addTarget(self, action : "onTap")
    square.addGestureRecognizer(tapForSquare)
    square.userInteractionEnabled = true
    square.multipleTouchEnabled = true
  }

  func onTap() {
    println("square tapped")
  }
}
```

I have both squares on the screen but the tap action only works on the second one. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: I suspect the issue has to do with the fact that only one view controller can be a parent at once, so since you're setting widget2 as a parent 2nd, it's the only parent view controller. I'm trying to find documentation to corroborate this -- but I think perhaps that's why it's the only view controller that's receiving touches. In general though, I'd recommend a different method than embedding containment view controllers (as opposed to simply embedding UIViews) to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`onTap()` takes an argument. It should be:

`onTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)`

and add a colon after "onTop" in this line:

`tapForSquare.addTarget(self, action : "onTap")`

Comment: That's not true. It doesn't *need* to take an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, it seems interestingly this works only if you set the parent views frame as well.

So something like:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x : viewX, y : viewY, width: 50, height: 50)
    let square = UIView()
    square.frame = CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.view.addSubview(square)
    ...
```

}